# Is it possible (without JS) to have a parent div shrink to fit the wrapping children elements?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-float

Here's a JSfiddle I set up to demonstrate what I'm trying to solve:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9r6gbj4/

I'd like the red box on the right to automatically "snap" to fit as many columns of the white boxes as it can.  I don't want to use justify-content.  On my screen at the moment it shows 4 white boxes on each row, and then about-half-a-white-box of space at the right.  I'd like the red box to shrink down to fit those 4 white boxes "just right".  If I make the screen smaller it'd snap down to 3 boxes, then 2, then 1, etc.  The blue box on the left should take up the extra available space.

I wonder if this might be possible using a combination of flex-box/grid/float, but no amount of googling I did threw up any potential solutions, other than articles from a few years ago using javascript.

Another possibility would be to hard-code CSS media breakpoints, but that feels hard to maintain (and prone to problems when users have custom font-sizes set etc?)

I'm not interested in justifying the content - I want those 2em gaps between the white boxes to always remain 2em.

I *am* potentially ok with the white boxes scaling up to fill the available space, but I'm not sure that's any more likely to have a solution than what I'm asking.

HTML & CSS:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  background: #666;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2em
}

#left,
#right {
  padding: 1em
}

#left {
  background: #def;
  margin-right: 2em;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

#right {
  background: #fed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

#right>div {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 1em
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam.</p>
    <p>Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis.
      Orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. In pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed
      turpis.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your right side is never going to snap to be a specific length because you set it to be 50% width.

Comment: I'd like it to be at least 50% wide, while not having any spare space in it.

Comment: After much reading of specs and fiddling around I've come to the conclusion that no, what I want isn't possible without media query breakpoints, so that's what I've done.